# Why does my Doctrine custom repositoty think, my entity is detached?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a weird problem with my custom Doctrine2 repository.

I have a DELETE-controller, which looks basically like this:

```
public function deleteAction(MyEntity $myEntity, MyEntityRepository $myEntityRepository)
{
    $myEntityRepository->remove($myEntity);
    $myEntityRepository->flushEntityManager();

    return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'Bye bye!']);
}
```

And the Repository's remove method looks like this:

```
public function remove(MyEntity $entity): MyEntityRepository
{
    $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);
    return $this;
}
```

This has worked before, but now, I get an Exception:

*Detached entity AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity@000000003b458c32000000007fd2994a cannot be removed*

I really don't know, why the EntityManager inside the Repository thinks, the Entity is detached. When I inject the EntityManager directly to my controller, everything is okay:

```
public function deleteAction(MyEntity $myEntity, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $em->remove($myEntity);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'Bye bye!']);
}
```

Any ideas on this? Why is the EntityManager I get from Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->getEntityManager() different from the one that is injected into my controller?

P.S. My other DELETE-actions don't have this problem and they all use their identical custom repositorys. This drives me crazy.

Edit: dumping `$this->getEntityManager()` within the repository comes up with:

```
EntityManager {#627 ▼
-config: Configuration {#461 ▶}
-conn: Connection {#471 ▶}
-metadataFactory: ClassMetadataFactory {#618 ▶}
-unitOfWork: UnitOfWork {#493 ▶}
-eventManager: ContainerAwareEventManager {#511 ▶}
-proxyFactory: ProxyFactory {#588 ▶}
-repositoryFactory: DefaultRepositoryFactory {#619 ▶}
-expressionBuilder: null
-closed: false
-filterCollection: FilterCollection {#598 ▶}
-cache: null
}
```

while dumping `$em` within the controller comes up with

```
DoctrineORMEntityManager_00000000644c03b80000000000dac8cc6811571fd60520ff7ea135d840b51abe {#410 ▼
-valueHolder59cfe1676bb7b138763071: EntityManager {#664 …11}
-initializer59cfe1676bb84613288121: null
}
```

Comment: What happens with that Entity before you try to delete it?

Comment: Get help with symfony debugger panel and in database section see list of queries generated by doctrine and if there is some roll back then manually try to execute these queries to see actual error may be its generating some kind of db related error

Comment: Only have one entity manager?  Using ParamConverter to inject the entity?

Comment: @ svgrafovNothing else happens, this controller is all, what happens within that request.
@Cerad Only one EntityManager, and yes, the Entity is injected via ParamConverter.
@ MKhalidJunaid I'll have a look at the queries, but I don't expect something to find there. This minimal controller does in fact nothing else.

Comment: Weird does seem to be an accurate description.  Any chance the action is being called twice?  Using any unusual doctrine related bundles?  Manually clearing the cache and sacrificing a goat might help.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid only a few selects on this and some other entity. No Errors or messages.

Comment: @Cerad No, the controiller is definitely not called twice. This one Entity uses the PUGX/shortid-doctrine-bundle for the id property. Maybe this is related to the problem. But it isn't plausible that this leads to differing detached states of one entity manager. But dumping the EntityManager in the controller looks very different (DoctrineORMEntityManager_00000000644c03b80000000000dac8cc6811571fd60520ff7ea135d840b51abe) than dumping it within the repository (EntityManager).

Comment: Not familiar with the PUGX bundle but I suspect it is defining it's own entity manager and plugging in it's own param converter.  At least that fits your symptoms.  Try bin/console debug:container | grep doctrine and see if there is any evidence of two managers.

Comment: I browsed through some of the PUGX code and did not see any entity manager stuff.  But you should still confirm that there is only one entity manager being defined.  Might be another bundle lurking about.

Comment: I don't know what it would look like if there was another EntityManager, bus the console command gave me doctrine.orm.entity_manager, which is an alias for doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager, and a doctrine.orm.entity_manager.abstract. I also read through the code of pugx/shortid-doctrine and pugx/shortid-doctrine-bundle, but both are not quite complex and I saw no evidence about anything related to this problem, too.

Comment: It would have a class of EntityManager.  Consider updating your question with the bundle section of AppKernel.php.  Or maybe a github link to your app's repository.

Comment: Thanks to all and particularly to @Cerad for your input. I finally solved the problem! Have a look at my (own) accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new empty Symfony project to reproduce the problem step by step. I got to the same error, when I implemented my entity listener, which has a helper class as a dependency, which itself has the MyEntityRepository as a dependency. Removing this dependency removed the problem with the detached Entity.

Some further investigation later, I realized, that EntityManager instances that are injected are sometimes new instances. To get the main instance injected (and to remove circular reference errors by the way), you can tag the entity listener service to be lazy:

```
AppBundle\EventListener\MyEntityListener:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    # the service must be public, when it's tagged lazy
    public: true
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, lazy: true }
```

**This lazy stuff solves my problem!**

But I still do not understand, why I get another instance of EntityManager injected to my repository, when another service gets this repository injected.

For the record, MyEntityRepository configuration:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Repository\MyEntityRepository:
    autowire: false
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false
    factory: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', getRepository]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity
```

The listerner service:

```
class MyEntityListener
{
    /** @var MyEntityHelper */
    protected $myEntityHelper;

    public function __construct(MyEntityHelper $myEntityHelper)
    {
        $this->myEntityHelper = $myEntityHelper;
    }
    // ...
}
```

and the helper service:

```
class MyEntityHelper
{
    /** @var MyEntityRepository */
    protected $myEntityRepository;

    // this injection of MyEntityRepository creates the problem
    // with the two instances of the EntityManager
    // unless the MyEntityListener is tagged as lazy
    public function __construct(MyEntityRepository $myEntityRepository)
    {
        $this->myEntityRepository = $myEntityRepository;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Sounds like the shared service attribute got set to false but I don't see how.  Plus, injecting the entity manager into an entity listener normally triggers a circular dependency exception.  In most cases you want to just pull the entity manager from the event.

Comment: This was the thing, I changed: Before, this was a `doctrine.event_listener`, where I pulled the EntityManager from the event. But now the logic was outsourced to the helper service getting the EntityManager injected and the listener was changed to a `doctrine.orm.entity_listener`, where the methods receive the Entity instead of the event and use the helper to to the work. I didn't see this warning sign in Doctrine's documentation: "An Entity Listener could be any class, by default it should be a class with a no-arg constructor." How is such a listener supposed to leverage services then?

Comment: It's not a doctrine limitation per se.  Rather, it is the way the Symfony container creates the entity manager and adds the listeners.  Since the container itself has no knowledge of Doctrine, the listeners are added by using setter dependency injection.  Kind of a neat trick.  It's instructive to look at the generated container code in the cache directory to see how it all fits together.

Comment: Having said that, my own experience is that Doctrine entity listeners have a great many constraints on their functionality.  Whenever I have been tempted to use the entity manager from inside of a listener, I hit obstacles of one sort or another.  In any event (pun intended I guess) you could adjust your helper functions to take an entity manager as well as the entity as input.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, this helps a lot to understand what's going on. I didn't expect such side effects, because neither the helper service nor the listener have anything to do with the EntityManager, since all the database stuff is capsuled within the repository, which is injected to my controllers and my helper services and has access to the EntityManager by default. I refactored my code lately to get nearly all those EntityManager dependencies out, moving all database work to the repositories. I thought that was a good idea. :/